# Retorno de valores en Genexus 18 al ejecutar SPs que devuelven registros

Tags: sql, transacciones, return, genexus18

Estoy trabajando con Genexus 18.
Tengo algunos SP (en SQL Server) ya creados que regresan valores.

Sé que desde Gx puedo mandar a ejecutar SP's a través del comando 'SQL':

```
&SSQL = "execute miSP Parametro1,Parametro2..." 
SQL [!&SSQL!]
```

Pero hasta ahora esto sólo me sirve para SP's que afectan información y no regresan valores/registros.

Por el momento la forma en que me enfrento a esto es ejecutar el SP y recupero los valores a través del comando SQL de Gx y de una tabla, lo que hago es que simplemente lleno esa tabla al final del SP y luego ya desde Genexus con un simple For Each leo los valores de esa nueva tabla.

Pero ¿cómo podría hacerlo sin utilizar tablas extras/nuevas, es decir, directamente ejecutar el SP que al final tendrá un Select.. y recuperar los valores desde Gx?

Ya que para cada SP de este tipo tendría que crear una nueva tabla...

Casi no hay información al respecto, pero he leído que a través de transacciones dinámicas o mediante DataViews es posible, ¿alguien lo ha realizado, cómo hacerlo?

Comment: La tabla dónde salvar los resultados del SP la conoces o la puedes definir de antemano? es decir, antes de llamar al SP?

Comment: Lo que justamente quiero hacer es no utilizar tablas, sólo ejecutar el SP que al final tendrá un Select ... y recuperar lo que me devuelva ese select, pero sin crear nuevas tablas.

Comment: Tal vez sea la única forma que tiene Genexus, pero francamente no lo sé por que no tengo idea, como lees los datos luego de llamar el Sp que inserta en la tabla?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Pues justamente como ya tengo los datos insertados en la tabla, sólo recorro con un For Each a esa tabla.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de tablas temporales, podrías usar variables tipo tabla, por ejemplo:

```
Declare @tablaResultado table(col1 Tipo, col2 Tipo..
insert into @tablaResultado(col1, col2..) exec MiSP 'param1', 'param2'

SELECT col1, col2.. FROM @tablaResultado
```

Dado que la instrucción final es un SELECT, es de esperar que Genexus tome el resultado y seas capaz de iterar por él con el simple `For Each` que ya mencionas.

Comment: No requiero utilizar nuevas tablas, solo ejecutar el SP que tendrá al final un 'select' y poder recuperarlo desde GX (pero sin crear tablas)

Comment: No estoy creando nuevas tablas. Una variable tipo tabla no es una tabla que quede en el sistema. Al terminar de ejecutarse la consulta, desaparece.

Comment: ¿Has trabjado con Genexus? Porque no puedo leer una variable tipo tabla desde Genexus, no tiene sentido.

Comment: ¿Leíste el código? No _lees_ ninguna variable, en la tercera sentencia haces un select de la variable tipo tabla. Lo que Genexus va a _recibir_ es un _cursor_ (dataset) con ese resultado, pues el resultado no es distinto de hacer un select a cualquier otra tabla. Solo que, no creas ninguna.

Comment: Según entiendo, tendrías que utilizar un objeto Query para el efecto.

Comment: Sí, leí el código, y entiendo a qué te refieres, pues en ese caso el SP en vez de devolver la información por tablas lo haría con la variable tipo tabla, pero eso no es posible leerlo desde Gx. Y el objeto tipo query no funciona porque es más para crear reportes y gráficos a partir de consultas, pero a partir de un nuevo query, yo solo requiero obtener los valores que devuelva el SP y llenar un GRID/Exportar un reporte (pero sin crear gráficos ni rehacer el código en Gx), saludos.